# What is the technical difference between Vue's native serverPrefetch() and Nuxt's new fetch() hook for server side rendering

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

What is the technical difference between Vue's native `serverPrefetch()` and Nuxt's new `fetch()` hook (Nuxt >= 2.12). I struggled to use `fetch()` in Nuxt `layout` until I discovered `serverPrefetch()`. Both able to fetch data on server for SEO and both have access to `this` context, but I found using `serverPrefetch()`, the data was rendered to DOM much faster. I'm looking for some technical details, before making decision if I should replace all `fetch()` with `serverPrefetch()`

---

Those are the benchmarks that I've did

```js
// took 166.585ms
serverPrefetch() {
  console.time('serverPrefetch')
  const test = async () => await this.fetchPosts()
  return test().then(() => console.timeEnd('serverPrefetch'))
},

// took 180.386ms
fetch() {
  console.time('fetch')
  const test = async () => await this.fetchPosts()
  return test().then(() => console.timeEnd('fetch'))
},
```

Comment: @kissu thanks for your comment. I'm looking for technical differences between the two. I know fetch() has some useful features like $fetchState.pending that's pretty handy, but would be good to know the technical differences or if they are the same under the hood.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After playing around for a while. I'm sharing my experience.

**Nuxt fetch() vs serverPrefetch()**

Both are almost identical under the hood, and the performance are similar. The difference is Nuxt fetch has additional hooks that are useful helpers for UI rendering.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-if="$fetchState.pending">Loading...</p>
    <p v-else-if="$fetchState.error">Error...</p>
    <ul v-else-if="data.length">
      …
    </ul>
    <p v-else>No data available</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Nuxt fetch() vs mounted()**

We can also use `fetchOnServer: false`, which will process only on the client side as an alternative to the vue native `mounted` lifecycle to take advantage of the `$fetchState` hooks in UI component.

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      posts: []
    }),
    async fetch() {
      this.posts = await this.apiCall()
    },
    fetchOnServer: false,
    methods: {
      apiCall() {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. If you're going the Nuxt way, I'll recommend using `fetch()` still, because it will be more integrated into Nuxt, hence more flexible (on top of having some nice helpers/cache).

Also, how did you benchmarked this?

> the data was rendered to DOM much faster

---

You need to take into account that Nuxt3 is coming by the end of the year (probably, beta inc soon), so if you use `fetch()` or alike, you will not need to update your whole codebase because Nuxt will take care of this.
What I mean, is that `serverPrefetch` will be probably different (native SSR with Vue3) is probably not as polished as Nuxt can offer.

Nuxt is still the best solution for SSR/SSG that the Vue ecosystem can offer.
Of course, you can make your own thing with vanilla Vue but you'll probably face some difficulties at some point. For ease of mind, I do recommend to try to make this work with `fetch()`.

Comment: @samchuang you're not supposed to write that kind of code in comments. I've edited your question with this. As for the content of the benchmark itself, this is some pretty inaccurate and naive tests. I'd say that you need to have better conditions and remove as much variables as possible. You ran it how much times? Also, 15ms on frontend is really not that decisive tbh.There will be far more decisive things to consider if you're planning on performance. And if you are **really** regarding those few ms, you should consider SolidJS or Svelte. I assume that it's fine and you're not 15ms short.